# Hi, I'm new to PL/SQL and I want to know how to add a variable type in a package

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

I want to know how is  ROT_TMLN_ARRAY type added to a variable in sql developer. I see that ROT_TMLN_ARRAY is also a type and I want to create something similar with another variable.

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY AS PKG TMLN
PROCEDURE SP TMLN SVC (
rotnPrngNb IN VARCHAR2
empiRotnDetails OUT ROT_TMLN ARRAY)
```

Comment: @OldProgrammer - how do I create a custom variable type in SQL developer

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375

Comment: It's irrelevant whether you are using SQL Developer or PL/SQL Developer. These are desktop tools for working with Oracle. The question is about PL/SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

U can add the variable as a Type in both IN or OUT Parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_TMLN_SVC(I_ID IN NUMBER,
O_RESULT OUT T_TABLE)
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT OWNER_TYPE BULK COLLECT INTO O_RESULT FROM OWNERES WHERE OWNERS_ID=I_ID;
END P_TMLN_SVC;
```

Calling Statement:

```
DECLARE
T_ARRAY T_TABLE;
BEGIN
P_TMLN_SVC(100,T_ARRAY);
END;
```